# How I know what sequence number is expecting my sender channel?

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm confused with the value that I have to reset my receiver channel.

I have the follow message:

```
Explanation: The local and remote queue managers do not agree on the next message sequence number. A message with sequence number 2854050 has been sent when sequence number 4078760  was expected.
```

Does the receiver channel have to be reset to 2854050?

What problems can I have if I use the wrong number?

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc, I reseted the RCVR to 2854050, and seem worked it

Comment: Hello @lucy-cabrera, How to reset receiver channel seq number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queue manager for both Sender (`SDR`) and Receiver (`RCVR`) channels will have the same exact error message message.

The following portion of the message is telling you the `SDR` channel sent a message with sequence number 2854050.

> A message with sequence number 2854050 has been sent

The following portion of the message is telling you the `RCVR` channel was expecting sequence number 4078760.

> when sequence number 4078760 was expected

---

If you want to make it work from the `RCVR` side queue manager then you would reset the `RCVR` channel sequence number to 2854050.

Note that a `SDR` channel can be reset to ANY sequence number and the corresponding `RCVR` channel will accept and reset its own sequence number to match what the `SDR` specified the next time a persistent message is received.

---

The next two sections of this answer are providing additional information that applies if the `RCVR` channel has a low privileged `MCAUSER`.

---

If the `RCVR` channel has a `MCAUSER` the user will need authority to allow the `RCVR` side channel reset to complete successfully.  What authority is required has changed over time, see below for further details:

The following versions of MQ require `+altusr` authority for the `MCAUSER` of a receiver channel to perform `SEQNUM` resets:

```
7.0.0.0 - 7.0.1.9
7.1.0.0 - 7.1.0.2
7.5.0.0   only
```

The following versions require `+dsp` and `+ctrlx` authority for the `MCAUSER` of a receiver channel to perform `SEQNUM` resets (Changed in APAR [IV31952](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV31952)):

```
7.0.1.10 and later
7.1.0.3  and later
7.5.0.1  and later
8.0.0.0   -  8.0.0.3
```

The following versions require only `+dsp` authority for the `MCAUSER` of a receiver channel to perform `SEQNUM` resets (IBM via a PMR indicated a internal defect changed the behavior):

```
8.0.0.4     and later
9.0.0.0 LTS and later
9.0.1   CD  and later
```

I suspect that the fact MQ still requires `+dsp` permission at the levels mentioned directly above  is a defect but I have not had time to report it to IBM via PMR.

---

For a `SDR` channel side reset, if the corresponding `RCVR` has a `MCAUSER`, in some cases the user will need authority to allow the channel reset to complete successfully.  What authority is required has changed over time, see below for further details:

The following versions of MQ require `+altusr` authority for the `MCAUSER` of a receiver channel to perform `SEQNUM` resets:

```
7.0.0.0 - 7.0.1.9
7.1.0.0 - 7.1.0.2
7.5.0.0   only
```

The following versions require `+dsp` and `+ctrlx` authority for the `MCAUSER` of a receiver channel to perform `SEQNUM` resets (Changed in APAR [IV31952](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV31952)):

```
7.0.1.10 and later
7.1.0.3  and later
7.5.0.1  and later
8.0.0.0   -  8.0.0.3
```

The following versions require no special authority for the `MCAUSER` of a receiver channel to perform `SEQNUM` resets (IBM via a PMR indicated a internal defect changed the behavior):

```
8.0.0.4     and later
9.0.0.0 LTS and later
9.0.1   CD  and later
```

Comment: Hi @JoshMc , We are facing similar issue ... Should we reset sequence number on sender channel and try? Or if we have to reset receiver channel seq number How can we do that? Out of RESETSEQNO , LSTSEQNO and CURSEQNO which one we need to reset?

Comment: The command is `RESET CHL(CHANNEL.NAME) SEQNUM(VALUE)`  If run on the SDR you can specify any value, if run on the RCVR the value must be match what you see in the error.